# Is c# List's array being shifted when i extract an element?

Tags: c#, .net, list, unity-game-engine, mono

I implemented a generic Pool System for any GameObject in Unity.
When i remove a GameObject from List<> i always take the last one to avoid shifting of the array used in List's implementation. Didn't find anything useful on the internet so tried to figure it by myself.
Is that useful or i'm just doing useless code?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PoolSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>> pool = new Dictionary<string, List<GameObject>>();

    #region cached
    private static GameObject lastReturned;
    #endregion

    public static GameObject GetElementFromPool(GameObject g)
    {
        if (!pool.ContainsKey(g.name))
        {
            lastReturned = Instantiate(g) as GameObject;
            pool.Add(g.name, new List<GameObject>());
            lastReturned.name = g.name;
            return lastReturned;
        }


        if (pool[g.name].Count == 0)
        {
            lastReturned = Instantiate(g) as GameObject;
            lastReturned.name = g.name;
        }
        else
        {
            lastReturned = pool[g.name][pool[g.name].Count - 1];
            pool[g.name].RemoveAt(pool[g.name].Count - 1);
        }

        return lastReturned;
    }

    public static void AddToPool(GameObject g)
    {

        if (!pool.ContainsKey(g.name))
        {
            pool.Add(g.name, new List<GameObject>());
        }
        pool[g.name].Add(g);

    }

}
```

I added all suggestions in answers and comments, **thanks everyone for help**. Adding changed code below, maybe someone will find it useful

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PoolSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Stack<GameObject>> pool = new Dictionary<string, Stack<GameObject>>();

    #region cached
    private static GameObject lastReturned;
    private static Stack<GameObject> lastUsedStack;
    #endregion

    public static GameObject GetElementFromPool(GameObject g)
    {
        if (pool.TryGetValue(g.name, out lastUsedStack))
        {
            if (pool[g.name].Count == 0)
            {
                lastReturned = Instantiate(g) as GameObject;
                lastReturned.name = g.name;
            }
            else
            {
                lastReturned = pool[g.name].Pop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastReturned = Instantiate(g) as GameObject;
            pool.Add(g.name, new Stack<GameObject>());
            lastReturned.name = g.name;
            return lastReturned;
        }

        return lastReturned;
    }

    public static void AddToPool(GameObject g)
    {
        if (!pool.ContainsKey(g.name))
        {
            pool.Add(g.name, new Stack<GameObject>());
        }
        pool[g.name].Push(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Neil The .NET list is based on an array, it *is* actually shifted upon element removal. Doubly linked lists would have horrible random access time.

Comment: As a side issue, don't use `ContainsKey` like that. Use `TryGetValue` instead, to avoid doing the hash lookup twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Indexed Collections have this property. If you remove a element at any point, all the following ones move up. That is one big reason you will not find a `ConcurrentList[T]`. Making one would just rush you head first into Index race conditions. It is impossible to have a List be concurrent without accounting for the using code.

Keyd Collections (`Dictionary[int, GameObject]`) do not have this drawback. Note that there are special collections for certain opeartions. The Queue (first in, first out) and the Stack (first in, last out). Those might be more fitting for your scenario.

Comment: The Stack works perfectly with O(1) for push and pop (and O(n) push cost with full stack),  Thank you very much!

Comment: @victordabija: And it even has a Concurrent Variant, for those Multitasking scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> When you call RemoveAt to remove an item, the remaining items in the list are renumbered to replace the removed item. For example, if you remove the item at index 3, the item at index 4 is moved to the 3 position. In addition, the number of items in the list (as represented by the Count property) is reduced by 1.
>
> This method is an O(n) operation, where n is (Count - index).